# Porque no me funciona el contador?

Tags: java, contador, switch

En el switch no me esta contando las cantidad de veces que coloco una de mas 3 materias y no se por que?

```
 while (!materia.equals("taller") && !materia.equals("fundamentos") && !materia.equals("matematica")){
                            System.out.println("Error: Ha ingresado una materia inexistente");
                            System.out.println("Ingrese la materia del alumno");
                            materia = input.nextLine(); 

                                     switch (materia){
                                     case "taller": matTaller++; break;
                                     case "fundamentos": matFundamentos++; break;
                                     case "matematica": matMatematica++; break;
                                     default:;
                                     }
```

Comment: ¿A qué hace referencia el `input`? ¿Cuál es exactamente el resultado esperado al ejecutarlo? ¿Tiene algún valor inicial la variable `materia` con esos 3 valores? En este caso, simplemente no estaría entrando dentro del while. Si no, no veo ningún problema con ese código

Answer (score 0):

Compañero, como te muestro a continuación sí funcionarían. En vez de usar un while, he usado un **do-while**, para que primero pida datos al usuario y, en caso de que no coincidir la matería indique que hay un error y vuelva a pedir daros. Al introducir una materia válida, el contador de dicha materia aumenta y el programa sale, ergo, el contador funciona:

**Código**:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String materia = null;
    int matTaller = 0;
    int matFundamentos = 0;
    int matMatematica = 0;
    
     do {
        System.out.println("Ingrese la materia del alumno");
        materia = input.nextLine();

        switch (materia) {
            case "taller":
                matTaller++;
                break;
            case "fundamentos":
                matFundamentos++;
                break;
            case "matematica":
                matMatematica++;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Error: Ha ingresado una materia inexistente");
        }
        
        System.out.println(matTaller);
        System.out.println(matFundamentos);
        System.out.println(matMatematica);
     } while (!materia.equals("taller") && !materia.equals("fundamentos") && !materia.equals("matematica"));
    }
}
```

**Salida**:

```
Ingrese la materia del alumno
asd
Error: Ha ingresado una materia inexistente
0
0
0
Ingrese la materia del alumno
taller
1
0
0
```

Desconozco si tienes que implementar alguna otra funcionalidad, pero los contadores así estarían funcionando.

Espero haberte ayudado :)